# Is it natural to say "punch something/someome at full tilt" meaning to punch the thing or someone as hard as one can possibly can?

Tags: collocations

Is it natural to say  *punch something/someome at full tilt* meaning to punch the thing or someone as hard as one can possibly can? For example:

> The was punching the punching bag at **full tilt**. He must have been letting off steam.

If it isn't, then what would you say to mean that someone punched something as hard as they could?

Comment: Full tilt usually means, in connection with movement, e.g. running,  'as fast as possible'. I would not use it about boxing.

Comment: Seems fine if not ideal, but it's colloquially referred to as punchbag more than punching bag.  He was punching the punchbag.  Going at full tilt sounds more natural

Comment: @BruceMurray That may be regional. I've heard "punching bag" much more than "punchbag" in the US.

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty: Definitely "regional". I'd always use single-word ***punchbag*** myself, and to be honest until just now I thought most other people did too. But I see from NGrams that [even in BrE,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=punching+bag%2Cpunchbag&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpunching%20bag%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpunchbag%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpunching%20bag%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpunchbag%3B%2Cc0) ***punching bag*** appears to be *slightly* more common. And in AmE, the one-word form is virtually unknown.